# Highcharts Firefox issue

Tags: firefox, highcharts, cross-browser

I use Highcharts to read my solar panels output in a 24-hours graph. In all browsers the rendering is fine though in Firefox it does not work out properly. I read about date coding issues, though no clue where to start.

Expected one:
[image: Highcharts OK]

In Firefox:
[image: Highcharts Firefox]

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please share the current chart code with us, you can also refer to the [How to Ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly with what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi @Harry, Could you provide us with some minimal live example that presents the issue? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sa3qyko9/